# Custom Delegates null

Tags: ios, objective-c

In `FirstViewController` I have a tableview. A button is clicked to push `SecondViewController` where an item is typed in and a button is pressed to add the item.

In `SecondViewController.h` file there is:

```
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)itemAdded:(NSString *)item;

@property (nonatomic, weak)id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In `SecondViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender {
 [self.delegate itemAdded:@"someText"];

}
```

In `FirstViewController.h`

```
@interface SecondViewController: UITableViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, SecondViewControllerDelegate>
```

In `FirstViewController.m`

```
-(void)itemAdded: (NSString *) item{
[self.items addObject: item];
}
```

Everything is working fine except that the `[self.delegate itemAdded:@"someText"];` doesn't call the `itemAdded` function in the `FirstViewController` can anyone help?

Comment: Where do you *set* the delegate of the second view controller?

Comment: I dont, how do i set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that the delegate of the second view controller is nil. Where ever you create the second view controller, presumably somewhere in the first view controller, you need to set `secondViewController.delegate = self` so that when the second view controller needs to call back to the delegate, it's pointing to the first controller instead of nil.

Also, you have declared the SecondViewController class as a SecondViewControllerDelegate, but this is incorrect. A second view controller wouldn't be the delegate of itself, rather a FirstViewController will be. You need to move  to the interface of FirstViewController, then the compiler won't complain when you try to set a FirstViewController as the delegate to the SecondViewController.